# Fill a part of an panel with color

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I am trying to get a sort of error resolver window. It's an panel to be included in a Windows Form. I used the FillRectangle method to draw a little rectangle in the panel but when i compile it and use it it won't show.

Here is my code:

```
public enum NotificationPanelState
{
    None            = 0,
    Error           = 1,
    Warning         = 2,
    Information     = 3,
    Popup           = 4,
}

private NotificationPanelState state = new NotificationPanelState();

public NotificationPanelState PanelState
{
    get { return state; }
    set { state = value; this.Invalidate(); }
}

public NotificationPanel()
{
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint
        | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);

    this.Size = new Size(200, 50);
    this.MaximumSize = new Size(200, 50);
    this.MinimumSize = new Size(200, 50);
    this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(20, 20, 20);
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.Clear(BackColor);


    Rectangle stateRect = new Rectangle(
        new Point(this.Size.Width - 10, this.Size.Height),
        new Size(this.Size.Width, 5));

    switch (PanelState)
    {
        case NotificationPanelState.None:
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(40, 40, 40)),
                stateRect);
            break;
        case NotificationPanelState.Error:
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0)),
                stateRect);
            break;
        case NotificationPanelState.Warning:
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(250, 200, 0)),
                stateRect);
            break;
        case NotificationPanelState.Popup:
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0)),
                stateRect);
            break;
        case NotificationPanelState.Information:
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 142, 250)),
                stateRect);
            break;
        default:
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(20, 20, 20)),
                stateRect);
            break;
    }

    //Draws error string
    e.Graphics.DrawString(ErrorMessage, StringFont, Brushes.Black,
        new Point(this.Size.Width / 2, (this.Size.Height / 2) - 10), 
        new StringFormat { 
            Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter, 
            Alignment = StringAlignment.Center 
        });

    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

I must have done something stupid...

Here is how i used it:

```
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    notificationPanel1.PanelState = NotificationPanelState.Error;
    notificationPanel1.ErrorMessage = "ERROR 403 FORBIDDEN";
    notificationPanel1.StringFont = new Font("Segoe UI", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
    notificationPanel1.ForeColor = Color.Gainsboro;
}
```

It's just the drawing of the little rectangle in the bottom of the panel. It won't show.

Comment: Why do you call `base.OnPaint()`?

Answer (score 0):

call base.OnPaint() BEFORE you change the paint options... base.OnPaint() will remove any modifications you make to the object as it is expecting to start from scractch and will therefore wipe out what you did beforehand...

Comment: I changed that but it'll still not paint the little rectangle below. Should i use DrawRectangle instead of FillRectangle?

Comment: That will not make a difference other than what gets painted. Have you tried to add `notificationPanel1.Invalidate();`to the MainLoad event? Oh, and what about the text? It doesn't show either, right??